# Why do multiple exceptions break Node v12's async stacktraces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, v8

Node v12 shipped [zero-cost async stack traces](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit) which improves stacktraces when using async/await.

However if there are multiple `await` calls with caught exceptions in an `async` function, only the first exception caught will have a full stacktrace. The other exceptions' stacks start from the call site.

For example consider this scenario:

```
async function a() {
  await b();
}

async function b() {
  try {
    // OK - full stack trace
    await c();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  try {
    // Not OK - stack trace first frame is this line, previous frames lost
    await c();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function c() {
  throw new Error('whoops');
}

a();
```

Running the above outputs:

```
Error: whoops
    at c (test.js:64:9)
    at b (test.js:40:11)
    at a (test.js:34:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.js:66:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:777:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:788:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
Error: whoops
    at c (test.js:64:9)
    at b (test.js:45:11)
```

Why don't all exceptions have a full stack trace?